# PDE Evans, 1st edition, Chapter 5, Problem 14

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let $U$ be bounded, with a $C^1$ boundary. Show that a ''typical'' function $u\in L^p(U) (1\leq p < \infty)$
>   does not have a trace on $\partial U$. More precisely there does not exist a bounded linear operator
>   $$T:L^p(U)\rightarrow L^p(\partial U) $$
>   such that $Tu=u|_{\partial U}$
>   whenever 
>   $u\in C(\bar{U})\cap L^p(U)$

Comment: There is another answer at this website, the link is:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332599/pde-question-in-evans

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Construct an $L^p$ bounded sequence of continuous functions that look "nice" in the interior of $U$, but grow fast near the boundary. In order to construct this sequence explicitly, you can use the $C^1$ boundary condition in order to pass to local coordinates.

Comment: Another option is to build such functions out of $\operatorname{dist } (x,\partial U)$. That would work for rough domains too.