# With regards to a comment on Problem 5.14 from Evans PDE, absolute values.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332599/a-typical-lp-function-does-not-have-a-well-defined-trace-on-the-boundary).

> **Problem 5.14, Evans.** Let $U$ be bounded with a $C^1$ boundary. Show that a ''typical''
>   function $u \in L^p(U) \ (1 \leq p < \infty)$ does not have a trace on
>   $\partial U$. More precisely, prove there does not exist a bounded
>   linear operator
>
> \begin{equation} T:L^p(U) \to L^p(\partial U) \end{equation}
>
> such that $Tu = \left. u \right|_{\partial U}$ whenever $u \in C(\overline{U}) \cap L^p(U)$.

In the link, Sally offers the following solution.

> For completeness, I'll expand the idea in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266391/pde-evans-1st-edition-chapter-5-problem-14#comment581977_266405). The construction  does not require $C^1$ boundary, and works in every bounded domain. Let 
>   $$
> u_n(x) = (1-n\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial U))^+$$
>   which is a continuous function on $\overline{U}$. Since the sequence $u_n^p$ is decreasing, it is dominated by $u_1^p$, which is integrable. Hence 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_U u_n^p = \int_U \lim_{n\to\infty} u_n^p = 0
> $$ 
>   On the other hand, $$\int_{\partial U}u_n^p = \int_{\partial U}1\not\to0$$
>   which yields the claim.

Cookie comments the following in response, which didn't get a response back.

> And we shouldn't use absolute values either because if $\text{dist}(x, \partial U) > {1\over n}$, the function $u_n$ would be positive due to the absolute value and not $0$. If we just use the "$+$" like you introduced, then the negative part of the function $u_n$ would just simply be $0$. I hope that it is correct.

Could anyone help resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. If we took $v_n(x) = \lvert 1 - n\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial U)\rvert$ instead, which seems to be what Cookie considers, then the argument wouldn't work because we wouldn't have $v_n \to 0$ in $L^p$.

Answer (score 1):

If you used simply the absolute value, $|\cdot|$, instead of the positive part $(\cdot)^+$, then $u_n(x)$ would be large for $x\in U$ with $\operatorname{dist}(x,U^\mathrm c)>1$.  You would not be able to (easily) apply Fatou's lemma (or dominated convergence) to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n=0$ in $L_p(U)$.